# How do I plot two increasing variables?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot a gaussian wave packet which is time dependent.

```
Manipulate[Plot[ Abs[(Exp[-(x - x0)^2/2 a^2])*
Exp[I*k*x]/Sqrt[a*Sqrt[Pi]]], {x, -10, 10}], {x0, -10, 10}]
```

This is the code i used to plot the time independent part of it which only travels in x direction. But a gaussaian wavepacket's height decreases with time so for that I wrote the following code

```
Manipulate[Plot[ Abs[Sqrt[a]*(Exp[-(x - x0)^2/2 a^2])*
Exp[I*k (x)]/(Sqrt[Sqrt[Pi]]*Sqrt[a^2 + I*t])], {x, -10, 10}], {x0, -10, 10}]
```

So my question is how do I plot the wave packet with decreasing height as t increases?

Answer (score 1):

First, a Gaussian wavepacket is the sum of a lot of plane waves - you did not do that in your code. Second, to see the decay you need to put a dispersion relation - that is energy as a function of momentum.

Since you have a simple case here, you can initially use `Integrate` to find your real space profile.

```
a = 1
k0 = 1
en[k_] = k^2
g[x_, t_] = Simplify[Integrate[(Sqrt[a/Sqrt[Pi]] Exp[-(k - k0)^2/2 a^2])*
             Exp[I (k x - en[k] t)], {k, -Infinity, Infinity}],  Assumptions -> t > 0]

Animate[Plot[Abs[g[x, t]]^2, {x, -3, 10}, PlotRange -> {0, 5}], {t, 0, 3, 0.1}]
```

[image]

Here `k0` is the momentum of your wavepacket.

Comment: this only seems to be dispersing with time and not along the x axis. How do I do both simultaneously?

Comment: check the new answer